# How to eliminate old versions from GetListUsingItems

Tags: 2011

I am using below code to get the set of elements using the particular component

```
   Filter filter = new Filter();
        filter.Conditions["ItemType"] = ItemType.Page;
        // Use the filter to get the Structure Groups contained in this root Structure Group.
        Component objComponent = (Component)_session.GetObject(componentTcmUri);
        // Get the list of objects, using this component. Filter the objects by page type. 
        XmlElement _xmlElement = objComponent.GetListUsingItems(filter);
```

But it is getting the old versions as well. Does anybody know how to eliminate older versions or any other better way to get that component link by passing tcm

```
 String _dependentPageUri = _xmlElement.FirstChild.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID").Value;
            log.Info("_xmlElement****" + _xmlElement.InnerXml.ToString()+"*****");
            log.Info("_dependentPageUri" + _dependentPageUri);
            String currentPageUri = package.GetValue("Page.ID");
            if (currentPageUri != "")
            {
                if (currentPageUri == _dependentPageUri)
                {
                    if (_xmlElement.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
                    {
                        _dependentPageUri = _xmlElement.ChildNodes[1].Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID").Value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

All i need it PageURI using the TCM.

Comment: Can someone please help with how the " Old versions" filter can be applied using Interop?

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need to change the type of your `filter` to `UsingItemsFilter` and then set `IncludedVersions` property of it to `VersionCondition.OnlyLatestVersions`

Comment: I don't see that property for filter. i am using Tridion 2011..

Comment: Indeed, I've updated my answer

Comment: what is the assembly for UsingItemsFilterData. i searched http://www.sdl.com/ www.sdltridionworld.com . please refer some website to get tridion resources.

Comment: It's in Tridion.ContentManager.dll